# Unusual variable declaration

Tags: c++

What does it mean?

```
int * (*(*d)())[10];
```

I thought that it could be a pointer to array of 10 pointers to function that returns int. Am I right?

Comment: See the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: http://cdecl.org

Comment: Also, no, it's not an array of function pointers, it's a pointer to function that returns a pointer to array.

Comment: @Paranaix the insane C programmer's best friend (TM)

Comment: "A boon to teachers of trivia and people who want to make fun of the language", someone once said about the C declaration syntax.

Comment: @KerrekSB: And seekers of SWEET SWEET REPZ

Comment: It means the guy who wrote this is a masochist psycho. Stay away from him.

Comment: So people who upvote this question, do you think that it "demonstrates research effort" and "it is useful"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) tells us that this is:

> declare d as pointer to function returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to int

I recommend simply using that website next time if you are stuck.

Incidentally, if this is a declaration in real code that you are using, *run away*.

Comment: The last sentence. That. Also, congrats for 100k.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks! It was about time ;)

Answer (score 1):

for a declaration, read in a sequence starting with right first, right, left, right, left.

int * (*(*d)())[10];

```
d : right of d is empty (coz d enclosed by (), and you cant jump out of ())
  : left of d is *, so d is a pointer
  : right of (*d) is (), so d is a pointer to function
  : left of (*d)() is *, so d is a pointer to function that returns a pointer
  : right of (*(*d)()) is [10], so d is a pointer to function that returns a pointer to array of size 10
  : left of (*(*d)())[10]  is int *,
```

so finally, d is a pointer to function that returns a pointer to array of 10 int pointers

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, but I want to add a link

http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

that describes very well the **Right-Left rule** to decipher any C declarations, no matter how convoluted. It is easy to understand and use.